# allow access to a symlink when chrooted on the home directory

Tags: ftp, sftp

I have user that have a symlink to somewhere in the computer like this :

```
# ls -ltr /home/guirec0
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    root      24 Jan  9 17:56 int -> /disk2/clients/optik/int
drwxr-xr-x 2 guirec0 guirec0 4096 Jan  9 18:13 blabla
```

I use sftp to connect to this user. I have this setup in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` :

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftpgroup
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

So the root is changed and `/disk2/clients/optik/int` is not the same for `root` and for `guirec0`.

Is there a way to allow access `/disk2/clients/optik/int` for `guirec0`?

The goal of chrooting is to restrict access of the users.

Comment: Can you add another user, with the same uid, whose home directory is `/disk2/clients/optik/int` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use bind mount instead of symlink:

```
rm /home/guirec0/int
mkdir /home/guirec0/int
mount --bind /disk2/clients/optik/int /home/guirec0/int
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. So, I will have to write in `/etc/fstab` to make it persisting. I'm not very confortable with this. Is there a better way ?

Comment: @Dougui Move `/disk2/clients/optik/int` into `/home/guirec0/int` and symlink the other way round? Other than that, or remove the `chroot` from ssh config, no, bind-mount is the solution.

Comment: @xhienne I will use the mount solution but I have to find a way to add and remove from fstab safely

Comment: @Dougui You can add an entry to fstab with the "noauto" flag, so that it is not mounted automatically at boot.

Comment: @xhienne I don't want to change `fstab` manually or with a custom script because I don't want to do something wrong and not be able to reboot my os. Is there a command line tool to manipulate persisting mount points ?

Comment: @Dougui Every mount is persistent until the next reboot, just use the mount command given by GreyWolf. If by "persisting" you mean "surviving a reboot", then you must use `fstab` (or a custom script run at boot). It's not a big deal, we can give you the line to add, you test it and if it works, then it will also work at the next reboot. BTW, GreyWolf, it would be good to add the `fstab` line to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your source and destination are on the same filesystem, you can use a hard link:

```bash
ln /home/guirec0/int /disk2/clients/optik/int
```

This will survive a reboot.

But if `/disk2/clients/optik/int` is ever removed then re-created, the hardlink will refer to the **old** version.